# Getting Unique data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, select

I am trying to get list of latest messages. Here's the situation: When there are messages sent with exact same time, the sequel statement chooses all of them. I need only one message, the latest one, from each chat room. With help of @JuanCarlosOropeza (and his superb fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d506e/10 which I will forthwith include in every question I ever ask on this subject) I got the sequel statement below.

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT t.*,
               @rn := if(@friend = t.friend_id, 
                         @rn + 1,
                         if( @friend := t.friend_id, 1, 1)
                        ) as rn
        FROM ( 
                SELECT m.message, 
                       m.message_read,
                       m.message_date,
                       CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                            THEN m.receiver
                            ELSE m.sender
                       END as friend_id,
                       CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                            THEN p2.nickname
                            ELSE p1.nickname
                       END as name,
                       CASE WHEN m.sender = 4
                            THEN p2.image
                            ELSE p1.image
                       END as image
                FROM message as m
                JOIN profile as p1
                  ON m.sender = p1.user_id    -- sender
                JOIN profile as p2 
                  ON m.receiver = p2.user_id  -- receiver
                WHERE 4 IN (m.sender, m.receiver)
        ) as t
        CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @friend := 0 ) as var
        ORDER BY t.friend_id, t.message_date desc
     ) q
WHERE q.rn = 1
```

The above sequel statement does a great job; however, there is one flaw to it. `ORDER BY t.friend_id, t.message_date desc` does not take "exactly same message_date" into consideration. It may very well be impossible to have messages sent at the same time, but who knows?

friend table:

```
+----+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
ø id ø user1 ø user2 ø pending ø request_date ø
+----+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
ø  1 ø     4 ø     2 ø       0 ø 2018-05-09   ø
ø  2 ø     5 ø     2 ø       0 ø 2018-05-09   ø
ø  3 ø     1 ø     4 ø       0 ø 2018-05-09   ø
+----+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
```

profile table:

```
+----+---------+----------------------+---------------+-------+
ø id ø user_id ø nickname             ø email         ø image ø
+----+---------+----------------------+---------------+-------+
ø  1 ø       1 ø Welcome to MathMatch ø test@test.com ø NULL  ø
ø  2 ø       2 ø user3                ø NULL          ø NULL  ø
ø  3 ø       3 ø USER4                ø NULL          ø NULL  ø
ø  4 ø       4 ø elokiller            ø NULL          ø NULL  ø
ø  5 ø       5 ø USER6                ø NULL          ø NULL  ø
+----+---------+----------------------+---------------+-------+
```

message table:

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
ø id ø sender ø receiver ø message   ø message_read ø message_visible ø message_date        ø
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
ø  1 ø      4 ø        2 ø lulz      ø            1 ø               2 ø 2018-05-15 10:24:36 ø
ø  2 ø      1 ø        4 ø Hey Buddy ø            1 ø            NULL ø 2018-05-10 11:58:39 ø
ø  3 ø      2 ø        4 ø nooo      ø            1 ø               2 ø 2018-05-15 10:24:36 ø
ø  4 ø      4 ø        2 ø shut up   ø            1 ø               2 ø 2018-05-15 10:24:36 ø
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

It would be great if you know how to fix this problem. The result I am getting at this moment when I run the above sequel statement is as following.

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+------+
ø message   ø message_read ø message_date        ø friend_id ø name                 ø image ø rn   ø
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+------+
ø Hey Buddy ø            1 ø 2018-05-10 11:58:39 ø         1 ø Welcome to MathMatch ø NULL  ø    1 ø
ø lulz      ø            1 ø 2018-05-15 10:24:36 ø         2 ø user3                ø NULL  ø    1 ø
ø nooo      ø            1 ø 2018-05-15 10:24:36 ø         2 ø user3                ø NULL  ø    1 ø
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+------+
```

Result I expect:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+------+
ø message   ø message_read ø message_date        ø friend_id ø name                 ø image ø rn   ø
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+------+
ø Hey Buddy ø            1 ø 2018-05-10 11:58:39 ø         1 ø Welcome to MathMatch ø NULL  ø    1 ø
ø lulz      ø            1 ø 2018-05-15 10:24:36 ø         2 ø user3                ø NULL  ø    1 ø
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+----------------------+-------+------+
```

As you see, there are two messages from same friend_id, which is 2. I just want to retrieve one message from that friend. Thank you for taking your time. Any comment will be helpful~

---

Another scenario to concern.

Current message table:

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | sender | receiver | message   | message_read | message_visible | message_date        |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      4 |        2 | lulz      |            1 |               2 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |
|  2 |      1 |        4 | Hey Buddy |            1 |            NULL | 2018-05-10 11:58:39 |
|  3 |      2 |        4 | nooo      |            1 |               2 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |
|  4 |      4 |        2 | shut up   |            1 |               2 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |
|  5 |      4 |        2 | heha      |            1 |            NULL | 2018-05-15 10:36:11 |
|  6 |      1 |        4 | SUP MATE  |            1 |            NULL | 2018-05-15 11:04:24 |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

current result table:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
| message   | message_read | message_date        | friend_id | name  | image | rn   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
| Hey Buddy |            1 | 2018-05-10 11:58:39 |         1 | JUAN  | NULL  |    1 |
| nooo      |            1 | 2018-05-15 10:24:36 |         2 | user3 | NULL  |    1 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
```

expect result

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
| message   | message_read | message_date        | friend_id | name  | image | rn   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
| SUP MATE  |            1 | 2018-05-15 11:04:24 |         1 | JUAN  | NULL  |    1 |
| heha      |            1 | 2018-05-15 10:36:11 |         2 | user3 | NULL  |    1 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
```

Comment: What do you mean from "one message"?  Which one should be retrieved  and which one should be ignored?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour It does not really matter since both of those messages were sent at the same time. Based on the result above, getting "lulz" message makes more sense. If you look at the message table, there is a message with "heha" in it and this one is the latest one; however, the sequel statement above totally ignores that fact.

Comment: Can you format a ascii data table based on the example data what results you expect?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I just edited my question and added a result table I expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an ID to the resulting table then you can pick the latest id and group by the friend_id.

Assume you are able to build a view of the sorts below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MESSAGES` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `friend_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message_time` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `MESSAGES` (`id`, `friend_id`, `message_time`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2018-05-10 11:58:39'),
  ('2', '2', '2018-05-15 10:24:36'),
  ('3', '2', '2018-05-15 10:24:36');
```

You then will pick the messages with the max time grouped by friend id first and then you will pick the message with the maximum `id` in it. Which you can achieve with the following SQL.

```
SELECT MESSAGES.id, MESSAGES.friend_id, MESSAGES.message_time FROM

(
  SELECT max(id) as id, friend_id FROM
  (SELECT id,
          m.friend_id,
          m.message_time
   FROM MESSAGES m
   JOIN
     (SELECT friend_id,
             MAX(message_time) AS message_time
      FROM MESSAGES
      GROUP BY friend_id) mx ON mx.friend_id = m.friend_id
   AND mx.message_time = m.message_time) b GROUP BY friend_id
) a JOIN 
   MESSAGES on a.id = MESSAGES.id ;
```

Getting the results as required by the MESSAGES table in the above query should be fairly straight forward since you have done something similar as per your question.